# can I Use dynamic parameter more than one time on a template in expressionengine

Tags: ee

can I Use dynamic parameter more than one time (conditionally) on a template in expressionengine.

like

```
{if case1}
{exp:channel:entries ..... dynamic="off"}
stuff
{/exp:channel:entries}
{if:else}
{exp:channel:entries ..... dynamic="off"}
stuff
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the dynamic parameter more than one time in a template and you can use it inside conditionals as well.

Comment: But when I am using dynamic off more than one time the page break. and if I remove dynamic off from from one of channel tag it's shows fine but no results for where i remove dynamic off.

Comment: Please post your real code and give more details about what you're trying to accomplish.